# Сообщить разработчикам gcc?

Tags: gcc

Система Fedora 24, gcc version 6.3.1 20161221, параметры для компилятора -m64 -ffreestanding -O0
Компилирую, в том числе, следующий код

```
void set_int_handler(uint8 index, void *handler, uint8 type)
{
    asm("pushf \n cli");
    idt[index].selector = 8;
    idt[index].address_0_15 = (size_t)handler & 0xFFFF;
    idt[index].address_16_31 = (size_t)handler >> 16;
    idt[index].type = type;
    idt[index].reserved_IST = 0;
    idt[index].address_32_63 = (size_t)handler >> 32;
    idt[index].reserved2 = 0;
    asm("popf");
}
```

Компилятор видит что внутри функции нет других вызовов и пропускает инструкцию выделения памяти в стеке (sub rsp, <размер>). Перемещает параметры на место локальных переменных и когда выполняется PUSHF, затирает эти параметры. Как это обойти я знаю. Нужно ли сообщать разработчикам gcc об ошибке, или это не ошибка. Может я неправильно пишу на СИ (может какой то параметр нужно указать компилятору?)

Ассемблерный листинг

```
set_int_handler:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
; копируем указатель стека в RBP
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
; здесь при -m32 sub rsp, <size>
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, %ecx
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movb    %cl, -4(%rbp)
; gcc перемещает параметр в область локальных переменных
    movb    %al, -8(%rbp)
#APP
# 114 "interrupts.c" 1
; PUSHF затирает RBP - 4
    pushf
```

Код для баг-репорта

```
#include <stdio.h>

short func(short p1, short p2, short p3)
{
    asm("pushf \n popf");
    return p1 + p2 + p3 + 1;
}

void main(void)
{
    short a, b, c, d;

    b = 3;
    c = 4;
    d = 5;
    a = func(b, c, d);
    printf("%d  %d  %d  %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

gcc -m64 -o main64 main.c

gcc -m32 -o main32 main.c

Comment: Это не ошибка. Компилятор не обязан создавать ненужный (компилятору) стек-фрейм. [Разбор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853757/gcc-inline-assembly-with-stack-operation).

Comment: Если указана опция -m32, вместо -m64, то компилятор стек-фрейм создаёт. По этому и возник вопрос.

Comment: Приведите более полный код - вы упоминаете локальные переменные, но в коде у вас их нет. Плюс не помешало бы видеть ассемблерный листинг. `Может я неправильно пишу на СИ` - ну технически ассемблерные вставки - это уже не Си (они не стандартизированы, каждый разработчик компилятора реализует их как хочет), так что можно сказать что неправильно пишите) Для получения предсказуемого результата лучше написать отдельный ассемблерный модуль (но я думаю это вы и без меня понимаете).

Comment: Локальных переменных в коде нет, иначе компилятор бы сделал так  sub rsp, <размер> и проблемы бы не было. Компилятор перемещает параметры из регистров на "место" локальных переменных [rbp - 4],  [rbp - 8] ... Могу добавить ассемблерный листинг, в исходный вопрос. А то тук не красиво получится.

Comment: @JackKatch, думаю стоит, лишним не будет. Как отправите баг-репорт, киньте сюда ссылку, пожалуйста. Будет интересно посмотреть.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98320

Comment: @JackKatch, спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Поддержка отреагировала на баг-репорт. Написали что я попал в red zone. Теория "Аблязов. Программирование на ассемблере для x86_64. стр.240 5.1.3 Модель вызова". Идея в следующем, предлагается для ускорения не использовать команду PUSH, а использовать MOV когда параметров у функции много (их через регистры передают, а число их конечно) их сохраняют таким образом в стек, предварительно выделив там место. Не уверен (см. док.) но соглашение о вызовах (64) предусматривает область в 128 байт (red zone) для параметров процедуры. gcc чтобы быть "быстрым" пишет туда, не выделяя память (мне это не нравится) т.е. не передвигая указатель стека (gcc -m32 это делает). Есть флаг -mno-red-zone который заставляет gcc передвинуть указатель стека. Это не ошибка а так задумано. Не попадайтесь на это.

Comment: Или можно объявить локальную переменную в функции и сохранять в ней.